# How does one defend a military depot against Nazi-ish Sasquatch-vampires in a continent-sized post-apocalyptic wasteland?

Tags: post-apocalypse, military, military-defense, strategy, nuclear-war

There is a lengthy background to this, which I feel is relevant. Yes, the title is supposed to be somewhat B-movie-esque.

For some reason, there are Sasquatch-vampires (more on their biology later) on this version of Earth in addition to humans; they have been here since well before humanity left Africa, evolved in such a similar fashion that they were sentient (as we define a human as sentient) at essentially the same time, have integrated themselves into society in all aspects, and live world-wide. Asking how they got here is irrelevant to this question. Were they an alien tool for exterminating humanity that went rogue? Were they sent back in time by future humans for entertainment? Did they evolve naturally? Were they spun into existence by an Internet sci-fi writer? Those questions don't matter for the purposes of this one - they are here, here they are.

A certain group of Sasquatch-vampires were originally concentrated around an area that happened to have a technologically-advanced alien artifact in it. Advances derived from said artifact in their rough equivalent of the 1600s - simple things by our standards, such as "electricity", "vaccines", and "modern fertilizers", as well as a draconian government attempt at keeping the secrets behind the stuff under wraps - helped the local Sasquatch-vampire population and their human allies take over a land empire roughly comparable to [the Roman Empire at its height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Empire#/media/File:Roman_Empire_Trajan_117AD.png), as well as Scotland/Ireland and a larger portion of Central/Northern Europe.

However, said empire "maxed out" at approximately that size, and, despite the overall situation remaining relatively stable, its leaders realized that they were overextending, and that, despite their (shrinking) technological advantage, there were simply too many forces allied against them in order for them to hold all of their land.

Therefore, over the course of the next few hundred years, said empire slowly shrunk and retreated into its core territories over time until it merely took up the [Iberian Peninsula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iberian_Peninsula), submitting to various military disarmament and territorial dismemberment treaties along the way in exchange for guarantees of sovereignty. In their equivalent of the 2020s, new leadership (somewhat similar to Nazis, but with several notable differences) took over in a xenophobic, anti-human, pro-vampire military coup, immediately after which said state, despite being small and relatively weak at this point, became the first nation in the world to crack the code on nuclear technology due to their extraterrestrial technological edge (there's been a bit of a stifling of nuclear technology in this world due to a relative lack of warfare compared to ours).

Nationalistic and expansionistic sentiment, derived in part from the old Sasquatch-vampire empire, flared - "we have nukes, they don't" mingled with "they're on *our* land" mingled with "humans are food/an inferior form of sentient life" - meaning that, unlike the nuclear-armed United States after World War 2, this country was very interested in expanding its borders. They subsequently invade their "human-contaminated" neighbors, systemically nuking the tobacco juice out of them along the way and leaving behind a trail of devastated cropland, shattered infrastructure, and radioactive fallout. They expand to territory equivalent to their old empire, as well as the equivalent of [Nazi Germany's expansion into Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_Germany#/media/File:Greater_German_Reich_(1942).svg).

A few years into this, there's an ideological dispute ("should we simply reclaim the old empire, or should we try to take over *ze world*?"). A few years after *that*, the Glorious Leader/head honcho/center of the cult of personality/leadership figure is assassinated over it. All the generals who are leading this hyper-militaristic expansion effort decide to go their own way (long story short, there's a set of socioeconomic circumstances that allows them to do this without running out of supplies or personnel in the medium-term), resulting in warlordism that quickly devolves into a regional nuclear war with late-1940s/early-1950s-style [gun-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun-type_fission_weapon) and [boosted fission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosted_fission_weapon) weapons with yields in the hundreds of kilotons at most.

Essentially, every population center, military facility, shipyard, strategic command center, or other semi-important node in [this graphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe#/media/File:Europe_orthographic_Caucasus_Urals_boundary_(with_borders).svg), as well as a good chunk of North Africa, gets hit with an A-bomb.

Now (and only now), we get to more relevant context.

This particular part of a story I'm writing involves a group of human survivors attempting to hold out against remnants of the Sasquatch-vampire military that are operating in the region post-nuclear-apocalypse.

A Sasquatch-vampire is a rather formidable entity, whose physical characteristics I will list all of in case one is relevant to the question:

- they vary from six to twelve feet tall, and 85 to 470 kilograms/187 to 1036 pounds
- they are covered in a layer of thick, wooly hair similar to that of a [llama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llama)
- they are as intelligent as a human being, albeit these particular ones are rather unpleasant ones
- although nocturnal, they are not injured by, damaged by, or averse to light
- there is nothing supernatural about them
- all individuals have a [tapetum lucidum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapetum_lucidum), enabling them to see in low-light conditions
- they need to ingest approximately a teaspoon of human blood per day for its [T-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_cell) content (it *has* to be human blood, long story), but they get narcotic highs the more they ingest; moreover, these particular individuals would rather take it all for social/personal/mental/ideological reasons
- they feed on blood via scraping skin off of the neck or wrist [lion](https://reidparkzoo.org/blog/lions-have-rough-tongues/)-style and lapping up the resultant blood; unsurprisingly, this is highly uncomfortable for unwilling humans on various levels
- other than the blood, they eat "normal" (as defined by a human) foods, albeit in significantly greater quantities than a human
- they are capable of regenerating trauma notably faster than a human (i.e. within days rather than weeks), although they can't do things like "regrowing limbs" or "fixing organs" - they die to the same things humans do, just on a larger scale
- they have a lot more [neural activation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4269707/) than humans, meaning that they're proportionately stronger (I'd put it as "most of them can bench-press a motorcycle"), since they can "use more muscle per muscle"; the microtears/abrasions in their muscle tissues that are a result of this aren't really a problem due to their heightened regenerative ability
- they have a spring-loaded joint in their legs that enables them to vertically jump approximately three feet from a standstill without training
- they can climb walls gecko-style; [yes, this is scientifically possible even if they weigh half a ton](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/209073/87100)
- they are burst/ambush predators, and (unencumbered) can run at speeds comparable to/faster than Usain Bolt for a few minutes
- they have airbag-like sacs between their ribs to reduce damage due to blunt-force trauma
- they have bones that are a mix of bone and [nacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nacre); meaning that they can take significantly more compressive force relative to their size in comparison to "normal" life
- their skin is [bullet-resistant](https://www.pri.org/stories/2012-01-30/bulletproof-skin-made-spider-silk-human-tissue-video), if certainly not bulletproof
- while they can speak in human tones, they can also communicate in [infrasound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrasound) wavelengths between 20 and 0.1 Hertz
- they are warmblooded and appear on IR scanners
- their hearing and vision are probably describable as "peak-human", and their sense of smell is more like a dog's
- their joint fibers are made of [resilin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resilin#:%7E:text=Resilin%20is%20an%20elastomeric%20protein,Fogh%20in%20locust%20wing%2Dhinges.), enabling them to survive higher falls and forces with less damage than a human would withstand
- they can carry heavier body armor and weapons than humans; for instance, your average Sasquatch-vampire soldier might be lugging around multiple layers of Kevlar, a [SCAR-H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FN_SCAR) 7.62mm rifle, or a [Squad Automatic Weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M249_light_machine_gun) plus the ammunition required; crew-served weapons are something along the lines of 50-caliber machine guns or 20-millimeter anti-material rifles

The human characters are baseline humans as we would know them. They are an undersized (i.e. ~75% their normal number) [company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Company_(military_unit))-strength force similar to a modern US Army infantry company, without armor, artillery (beyond what's already organically embedded in their company; i.e. mortars), or air support who are attempting to defend a massive military supply storage, processing, and handling complex (such massive stockpiles of undamaged supplies - everything from munitions to food to spare parts - are part of the reason the warlord states aren't collapsing) **that was built *during* the atomic crusade/murderfest westward *by* the Sasquatch-vampires**, and which was too small to allocate a nuke to (approximately rectangular, 1500 meters to a side, with some buildings that are three stories tall, and in a relatively rural/isolated area) from roving bands of Sasquatch-vampires who are attempting to infiltrate it. There are about 500 human civilians in the place.

Sasquatch-vampire attacks are anything from a lone drifter/deserter (i.e. one individual armed with the weapons outlined above) up to a company-level force (also with the weapons outlined above, meaning no air support, no armor, and only the artillery they have with them), and anything in between; it might be one of them one week and a hundred the next. Other than the obvious physical differences and differences in armament, it's also useful to note that their organizational structure has mostly broken down: they are no longer military units, but bandits (albeit very well-trained ones).

There is one Sasquatch-vampire attack/attempt to get in a week, on average. It varies in magnitude.

The Sasquatch-vampires essentially possess the fanatic mentality of a top-notch SS unit, due to their adherence to one side of that ideological debate I mentioned (i.e. "humans are food/slaves, not people"); all the sane/non-mass-murderey ones are staying well away from this facility. The ones doing the attacking are not afraid of the humans and cannot be "bought" with donations of blood; they want to destroy the people resisting them, enslave the rest, and turn the facility into a hideout. Period. Done.

They're also not going to go away, because the humans at the facility are the only source of human blood in a wide radius, since most of the others are dead. Moreover, if two separate groups arrive, they'll probably ally with one another; the humans are the common enemy. They *aren't* a coordinated, organized force, they're a bunch of well-armed, well-trained bandits.

Supplies are essentially not a concern for the humans, given that they're in a military storage facility chock-full of them.

Said facility has a series of bomb-proof (i.e. anti-nuclear) personnel shelters that can fit every human on the premises, but next to none of the supplies. It also has a series of ammo bunkers to protect against shelling, meaning that the Sasquatch-vampires can't set off the human ammo supply via mortar. However, both are vulnerable to getting smoked out by foot infantry.

Food is not a concern for the Sasquatch-vampires for a few weeks after they arrive. Blood is not a problem ever because they need a mere teaspoon a day, and they probably caught and drained some band of roaming civilians a bit back - or brought them along as constantly-regenerating juiceboxes.

Them getting in long enough to shoot civilians/blow up supply storage facilities counts as a failure on the part of the humans, and it doesn't have to be a direct attack - they might just try infiltrating. Mortar/artillery/lobbed grenade attacks do not count due to the aforementioned personnel shelters and ammo bunkers; their win condition is "dig the humans out".

The humans holding out long enough for humanitarian (so to speak) aid and a subsequent peacekeeping force to get to them is their win condition; I'm presuming it would take ~half a year, despite the fact that essentially everything in the world was mobilized to support disaster relief after the nuclear war.

**"Retreat and blow the stuff up" is not an option for the humans, because this is in a post-nuclear wasteland, and it's the only cache of food/munitions for a while around, as well as the fortified position - sure, they could leave, but there's no "better position" to retreat to, and they can only take so much with them.**

Given *all of that*, here's my question:

**Given the superhuman physical attributes and general fanaticism of the Sasquatch-vampires, what tactics, strategies, or methods of combat and/or organization can the humans (both military and civilian; although the civilians are unarmed and not trained military-wise, they have access to a wide variety of infantry weapons) in this facility use in order to stop roving bands of them from getting inside and to kill them?**

Specifically, I'm looking for answers that take into account that the Sasquatch-vampires can subvert a lot of methods of keeping them out:

- Walls? They climb them.
- They'll probably win one-on-one with a human in any kind of fight, including a gunfight and especially in hand-to-hand combat.
- Chain link with barbed wire? They can pull it down.
- Shot to the torso? Won't put the bigger ones out of action for long, and unless they hit the heart it won't kill them instantly either.
- Trench? Jumped.
- 20-foot drop in full gear? Non-problem.
- They can outrun most humans in the facility long enough to catch them.
- IR scanners to detect infiltrators? They can wait for some of Europe's nastiest weather to get in their way.
- They can always attack at night if they so choose - i.e. when humans are most vulnerable.

Now, I recognize that you might say "normal tactics usable against humans would work on them too", but if Olympic-level physical capabilities, double-layered body armor, bullet-resistant skin, general physical durability, natural night vision, a capability for healing flesh wounds in days, the ability to hang upside-down from ceilings, and the grab bag of other *fun* stuff doesn't change how people deal with these things, I'd be *very* surprised.

Comment: Are these sasquatches from hell warmblooded, and if yes, do they appear on IR-scanners?

Comment: @DarthDonut Yes, and I will add that. Thank you. However, I would note that not only are there ways around IR, the odds are that they don't have enough IR to cover a 6-kilometer perimeter if there are things that get in the way - such as heavy rain, remember, this is in Europe.

Comment: Your question is asking what "the humans (both military and civilian)" can do - how many civilians are there and what are their capabilities?  (Apologies if the info is there, but that's a lot of text to read through!)  Also, how long do the humans need to hold out for - a week, a month, forever?

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Working on that, hold on, I just got two comments at once.

Comment: Another question: Expected maximum size of enemy force, number of allied combatants, willingness of the enemy to Overkill the target, does the enemy want to capture the depot for its supplies, or just kill everyone in there?

Comment: @DarthDonut I think I specified that: maximum enemy force size is probably going to be company-sized, only the military humans have weapons training but everyone can have a gun, enemy wants depot (and civilians - especially civilians) intact but are willing to raze the thing, especially since there are bunkers that civilians can survive in.

Comment: How to defend...  ...small doors?

Comment: @ShadoCat Defending small doors is easy, until they (a) throw a grenade in, (b) pull up a roadblock and use it as a shield, (c) set the structure on fire, (d) simply flank it and go around, or something else. If you're asking about whether they can fit through doors, yes, they can, because the original Sasquatch-vampire military built the place. If you're asking about the bunkers, their air flows are vulnerable to being sabotaged, and they can't hold enough supplies to keep everyone else alive for 6 months, which is why all the humans didn't simply retreat into them.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE, I was talking about how it would be hard for a large humanoid to squeeze through a small door.  It was meant as a joke.  However, if doors and halls where small, attacking would be a pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what concertina wire (think of what you would get with barbed wire crossed with a slinky) and the like are for.  You say they have a ton of military supplies--that will include plenty of it.

Yes, they can get through it--slowly!  That gives the snipers time to pick them off.

Edit:

It will not stand up to armor--I was thinking this was a pure infantry attack.  Against armor you want hedgehogs (take 3 I-beams and make a 6-pointed jack out of them.)  A big hedgehog can stop any tank ever deployed to date.

Also, explosives are very weak against both concertina wire and hedgehogs--only shaped charges have the punch to do much of anything and shaped charges are **very** short ranged.  You have to go right up to what you're blasting and affix the charge to it--and you'll need to do it twice to cut a larger I-beam.

This also means that the defenders not only can snipe anyone trying to sneak through, but they can also call mortar fire if they need to.  Airburst shells are devastating to infantry in the open and will do next to nothing to the defenses.  The attackers better not concentrate on cutting through any one spot.

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen so far; if they try to get through it stealth-wise, perimeter patrols will detect them eventually, and if they try to get through it violently/with vehicular attacks or explosives, it draws attention. Also, concertina wire doesn't need to be manned - it works 24/7/365, and weather doesn't stop it from working. The only caveat I'll bring in here is that the humans are going to need to deploy a LOT of the stuff; they have a 6,000-meter+ perimeter, and Sasquatch-vampires can probably jump over a few meters of it with a running start, even if they're in full gear.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE interspersing the area between rows of concertina with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punji_stick or trou de loup's would improve this even further by having the "empty" area behind the wire act as a bait for a long jump. These very heavy humanoids would then hit the spikes with increased velocity thereby greatly increasing the effectiveness of spike traps.

Answer (score 7):

### Don't

Don't build depots in vulnerable locations that is and don't necessarily try holding them.

Robert the Bruce discovered this in his wars against the English. Since the Norman invasion the English have loved stone castles, but Robert's campaign and combat style didn't work with stone castles, he needed to be more mobile. Castle warfare depends on holding the castle either until relief, logistics fail and the attackers have to withdraw, or the castle falls. Robert wasn't going to get relieved while holding a castle so his best option on taking one was to destroy it.

The reason I bring up this comparison is that you're in a similar situation or at least that seems to be the idea. Hopelessly outmatched in any confrontation you didn't choose, hence you must always be the party choosing when to have a confrontation and when not to.

**What this means is no fixed bases that you can't afford to immediately abandon if challenged.**

You'll also need something along the lines of a scorched earth policy when it comes to losing people. There must be no prisoners of war, no civilians captured, no living human who isn't poisoned may fall into enemy hands. **It's more important that they don't take any living humans prisoner than that you actually win any particular engagement.**

You have a race of obligate parasites, they can't survive in significant numbers without an equally significant human population and a solid logistical operation. To win this war you must deny them both these things.

### Other details

Their hide might be resistant to small calibre handguns of the type you're used to, but the old rules of weapons and armour always apply, sometimes one is dominant, sometimes the other. No person on your front line is going to be holding a weapon that isn't fully capable of piercing sasquatch hide. If they're known to be wearing body armour then all ammunition issued will be armour piercing. Without adequate weapons you do not put the person on the front line as it's a net benefit to the enemy (feeding). Also landmines, lots and lots of landmines.

Comment: The depot is already there, and certainly wasn't built in anticipation of nuclear warfare; these people are trying to defend a structure that they already found. Also, it isn't a war; this is a conflict over one building between a number of people that'll likely never get above a thousand between both sides.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE, the same still applies. If a building is a liability to you and a benefit to your enemy, destroy it. Don't try to hold it.

Comment: Well, they need to hold it, because it's the only non-outhouse/shack building for miles around, the city centers are irradiated craters, there aren't any nearby food sources (and they can't carry away enough of it to survive 6 months), and being caught outside at night MIGHT not be a GUARANTEED death sentence, but it's pretty damned close.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE, if there's nothing else around and no food sources why is that a strategic point other than for itself? Destroy it and move on, that way there really is no reason to be in that area.

Comment: The depot IS the food source - military rations and precanned stuff. The thing's huge. It doesn't have to last forever, either - just half a year before they get extracted.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE, someone needs to be up for a court martial for leaving them in that position.

Answer (score 1):

**Cyborg ninja sasquatch vampire ally.**

The last of her kind - augmented using alien technology and made immortal by a kindhearted genius scientist long dead. The cyborg ninja sasquatch vampires were to usher in a new era of peace and cooperation.  A dream which vanished in the atomic civil war.  Now as her genetic engineering fights a running battle against mutations suffered in the radioactive fallout, she tries to honor her creator's desire to help the humans against the worst of her own kind, and his.  She has taken up residence with this ragtag band of misfits, doing what she can to hold their place in this new cruel world.  She finds the perennial optimism and lightheartedness of the humans a balm against the pain and loss that haunts her cyborg sasquatch soul.

It is one on one combat every time with this blonde cyborg ninja sasquatch vampire.  She has a sidekick and armorer nicknamed Juicy who does not mind that periodic donation of a tablespoon; not even a little.  The ninja sasquatch is short as her kind goes at only six foot five; that was because of the size of the alien augmentations available.

And (season finale!) it turns out she is pregnant!

Comment: That's a great concept, but it sounds like she'd get taken apart by concentrated fire.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE - True; same as the unenhanced squatches.  Durable but not a god.  She would die under concentrated gunfire.  But she is faster, stronger, smarter, heals quicker, has ninja training and also 94 years of combat experience.  She does not wind up in situations where she is exposed to concentrated fire.  Unless it is absolutely necessary...

Answer (score 1):

**Rat Holes**

The only weakness you've given them is that fact that they're large. Everything humans can do, they can do better.

The only real defense is your base's doorways consist of small crawl spaces that people barely fit through.

Every room would have to be broken into by the enemy while your soldiers can pass freely.

Comment: Actually, I specified that the depot was built by the Sasquatch-vampire military. Odds are they built the doors large enough for the majority of their population.

Comment: Well as step one to defending said base, you seal the doors and make rat holes. The other option is to lose to a stronger, well armed and intelligent foe who can see in the dark, climb walls and jump like a freaking grasshopper. At least DC gave Superman a weakness to kryptonite.  You've given the enemy all the strengths of actual vampires but no weaknesses.

Comment: I'm going to point out that it's a tactical advantage; on the global level, there aren't many of them (something like 1 per 15 humans). It's why they haven't completely taken over the world. Also, they have a variety of psychological traits that mean that it's harder for them to organize on a wide scale; the way they survived was by being integrated into human civilization. However, on this scale, yes, they are abominations at direct combat. Also, I would point out that some of them come in 6-foot varieties...

Comment: Doesn't change my tactics. Even if the smallest of them can get through, you're facing just the smallest of them instead of all of them. Better to face one six foot one than twenty half ton behemoths. Even the six foot ones won't want to enter a tiny murder hole in a real hurry.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not a full answer, I think that is important aspect.  You write:

> civilians are unarmed and not trained military-wise, they have access
> to a wide variety of infantry weapons

You need to train military-wise every civilian capable.  Time is not an issue as you estimate it will take about an half a year till a relief force arrives.