# How could a human biologically climb vertical walls?

Tags: science-based, biology, physics, humans

I know that insects and geckos are able to do this because of clinging pads, or something like that, but they have a very low weight limit so therefore would not be able to support a human. So how else could a human climb like said gecko and/or insect?

Comment: Humans [can climb vertical walls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wr4rZEPQ09Y). You forget what it is that makes humans human: we make tools and we use tools. That is why we rule the Earth.

Comment: Actually if humans had on their torsos what geckos had on their feet humans would be able to stick to walls just as well. Only having the stuff on our hands will end up as a slippery business but some sticking will nonetheless occur and might allow some limited climbing ability if we were fast enough. Look up the van der Waals force.

Comment: I take it you mean an perfectly smooth vertical wall, because human rock climbers climb vertical walls all the time without problems.

Comment: If you think that for geckos weight is the limit, you better read this https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/209073/30492

Comment: Hi @Wilbur, welcome.. I've done a small edit in your question, removing the "hard-science" tag. I've attempted an answer (see below) but while writing it, I could not find a science-based answer, so a real *hard science* tag is not needed. If you don't agree, you can change it back, of course..

Comment: @Goodies That's completely fine, thank you for telling.

Comment: Doesn't amount to an answer, but giant pacific octopi can weight as much as a human, but through the power of suckers they can climb vertical walls. Apparently [it can also work for humans](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7L3DQU74v_s) to an extent...

Answer (score 2):

### It would require bio-engineering

**Impossible with existing human biology**

On a perfectly smooth vertical wand, the science based answer will be no. A human being cannot cause enough friction, certainly not with its existing,  biological means. No Vanderwaals force will keep you safely on the wand. I agree with AlexP's comment in the opening: a *tool* is needed for this.

**Even if you would stick..**

Suppose there would be some sticking substance. A genetic modification to climb walls like spiders do would be difficult to handle for humans, because we don't have 6-8 attachment points, only 2.. and human hands have a relatively small area to stick on the wand.. The sticking would need to carry the weight. It could be too strong, the human would not be able to detach the hand from the wand and proceed upward.

**Feet are not handy for this**

We are bipedal animals, our feet and knees have adjusted to move forward. Human feet cannot be used to help climb a vertical wall, even if they would stick.  When using the feet or toes to stick and move upward, your center of gravity moves off the wall.. which will require more sticking force. Or.. gravity will break a limb.

**How to solve the issue..**

Some sticking could be introduced on the *side* of the feet. But any solution would involve *very* strong arms, in the first place.. same time, make the "sticking" controllable: suppose the human hand could strengthen or weaken the sticking force, at will.. changing a chemical compound by sweating.. or use a non-chemical method: change the shape of the hand, to allow some kind of [Magdenburger hemispheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magdeburg_hemispheres).. but these changes would require bio-engineering !

Answer (score -2):

The science has already been done. Spiderman's webs and wall crawling are biologically possible AT HIS WEIGHT in real life if genetically engineered. The spider sense would use tiny hairs able to feel the weight of a single hydrogen atom, can even feel the frequency of light from photon pressure. Goethite protein matrix bones combined with electroactive polymer muscles would be able to bench press a few tons, leap around 40 feet, sprint on water, etc. Strong and fast. This isn't up for debate it's been proven.

Comment: If "it's been proven" then we would all be interested in some links to that proof.  (Not required for a "science-based" question, but it's a very strong assertion.)

Comment: You can research it yourself if your interested.

Comment: Just looking at one of the assertions - that it is possible to have tiny hairs that can feel the weight of a single hydrogen atom - seems extremely dubious for theoretical reasons.  (It probably would not be useful to have that level of oversensitivity for operating at standard temperature and pressure, but that is a separate issue.)  If you edit your answer to include links to where you have seen this is proven then your answer is likely to be better received.

Comment: Spiders have them 
Trichobothria https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichobothria a metamaterial able to hold a humans mans weight with a size 4 shoe exist. Said metamaterial works the same way. A human cannot, but a genetically modified human can.

Comment: To those who downvoted, get your head out of your ass. Everything I mentioned exists in the real world and can be done. I shouldn't have to hold your hand and explain basic stuff to you like a baby. I answered the question honestly. That's what matters.